# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS failed to detect an external HDMI monitor

Tags: external-display

On my new laptop (Asus Expertbook B9400 with i7-1255U, the GPU is embedded Iris Xe) I've a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS dual boot with the original Windows 11.
When Windows 11 is running, it can detect and use an external HDMI monitor correctly. But if Ubuntu 22.04 runs, it can't even detect that monitor.

I guess this issue might be related with kernel version, because the original kernel (5.15.0.58) works incorrectly when the laptop resumes from suspend state, and can be solved by upgrading the kernel to 5.17.15-051715-generic.
However, the external monitor detection issue can't be solved even if I upgrade the kernel to currently latest version (6.1.7).
Here is my current configuration:

```
$ more  /proc/version 
Linux version 5.17.15-051715-generic (kernel@sita) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-3ubuntu1) 11.3.0, GNU
 ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #202206141358 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jun 14 18:53:59 UTC 2022
```

Any anyone kindly provide any suggestion about how to debug/solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

With a USB Type-C to HDMI adapter, finally now I can use an external HDMI monitor with this laptop. Not a perfect solution though, it works anyway.